# Index of /ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/cnf

Tags: upgrade, downloads, hash, sha256

how do  i get the old version of ubuntu focal-updates  main cnf file on  12 January, 2022 as the size and hash-256  varies.? I need to get the exact hash 256 key and  file size  and not latest show in archive. but I want to download  Commands-amd64 xz older version as it showing  hash and size mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend taking drastic measures to solve this problem. Wait a few days for the update server to update its packages, and the problem will usually go away by itself. If you are prompted with a `[Y/n]` prompt when trying to update software from the terminal type `Y` in order to allow the software update to proceed.